# Why the contents of the form changes?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-1.10

I am tring to create dynamic list to `choices`of `symbol` field. I create that list inside view then put it to form constructor.

I want to take all data from `Dictionary` modal put it inside `choices` and show in my form but in the same time I dont need to show data which is already exist in `Requirement` modal.

At start it shows form correct:
[image]

Then when I try to click submit button form changes to this: (Whats wrong happenes?)
[image]

**models.py:**

```
class Dictionary(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(_('Symbol'), max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)

class Requirement(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    symbol = models.CharField(_('Symbol'), max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class RequirementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    symbol = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Requirement
        fields = ('symbol',)

    def __init__(self, final_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequirementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['symbol'].choices = [(x[0], x[1]) for x in final_list)]
```

**views.py:**

```
def requirement_add(request, project_code):
    data = dict()
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_code)

    requirements = Requirement.objects.filter(project=project_code)
    result = []
    for x in requirements:
         v = (x.symbol, x.name)
         result.append(v)
    full_result = [(x.symbol, x.name) for x in Dictionary.objects.all()]
    final_list= list(set(full_result) ^ set(result))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RequirementForm(request.POST, final_list)
        if form.is_valid():
            requirement_dict = dict(((x.symbol, x.name) for x in Dictionary.objects.all()))
            symbols = form.cleaned_data.get('symbol')
            requirement = form.save(commit=False)
            for symbol in symbols:
                requirement.project = project
                requirement.symbol = symbol
                requirement.name = requirement_dict [symbol]
                requirement.pk = None
                requirement.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            requirements = Requirement.objects.filter(project=project_code)
            context = {'project': project, 'requirement': requirement, 'requirements': requirements}
            data['html_requirement'] = render_to_string('project/requirement_list.html', context)
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = RequirementForm(final_list)
    context = {'project': project, 'form': form}
    data['html_requirement_form'] = render_to_string('project/requirement_add.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\reversion\revisions.py", line 296, in do_revision_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\views.py", line 616, in requirement_add
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 169, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 161, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 370, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 382, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 626, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Where is the rest of that view? And when exactly does the contents change?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hello! I add full code of my view. Check it pls. As I said in my post I have form where users can select checkboxes and then add data to database. In view I created dynamic list to `choises` but I have problems when click submit button in form. Form dont add data to database. It just change form content. I dont understand where I did mistake? Do you have any ideas?!

Comment: Also as I said in my post I want to take all data from Dictionary modal put it inside choices and show in my form but in the same time I dont need to show data which is already exist in Requirement modal. My dynamic list works. But form works wrong. In post you can see pictures of how form contect changes when I click submit button.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I add this `print([(x[0], x[1]) for x in final_list])` to my form just to know what kind of list goes to `choises`. When I open the form it shows me in console: `[('A', 'Requirement A'), ('B', 'Requirement B')]` which is corrent. Then when I select values in checkboxes and click submit button in console it shows me: `[('c', 's'), ('s', 'y')]` and raise error. Can you check my post again pls. Do you have any ideas whats wrong happens?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my mistake! It was in this line:

```
RequirementForm(data=request.POST, final_list=final_list)
```